# How can I programmatically check whether geo-tagging is enabled?

Tags: java, android, geolocation, android-camera, geotagging

I spent some time searching for an answer by myself, but couldn't find a solution.

Is it possible to check programmatically in my App, if the option for geo-tagging pictures in the settings of the camera-app (which I use) is activated or not?

Comment: Duplicates with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12740503 https://stackoverflow.com/q/40836603

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the [Camera.Parameters Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) but didn't find any relevant methods. I don't think it is possible to do that programmatically unless you re-implement `com.android.camera`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Seems like i have to read the tags of the pictures taken and write the GPS-coordinates manually, if the tags are empty.