# android - how to know geotagging feature from camera is on or no?

Tags: android, android-camera, geotagging

how to know geotagging feature from camera is on or no?

this code for open camera phone

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);


        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: hi E-place: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740503/geo-tagging-in-android

Comment: and check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942252/how-can-i-programmatically-check-whether-geo-tagging-is-enabled

Answer (score 0):

You can't check this programatically. You'll have to read the tags of the pictures taken and check the GPS-coordinates manually, if the tags are empty then geo-tagging is disabled.

You can use the ExifInterface class to read the EXIF metadata from JPEG images. Here's the official docs link explaining this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

Here's sample code you can use to read the tags:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```

```
if (null != bundle) {
    String filepath = bundle.getString(FILE_PATH_KEY);

    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append("Date & Time: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME) + "\n\n");
        builder.append("Flash: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH) + "\n");
        builder.append("Focal Length: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH) + "\n\n");
        builder.append("GPS Datestamp: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Latitude: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Latitude Ref: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Longitude: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Longitude Ref: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Processing Method: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Timestamp: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP) + "\n\n");
        builder.append("Image Length: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH) + "\n");
        builder.append("Image Width: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH) + "\n\n");
        builder.append("Camera Make: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE) + "\n");
        builder.append("Camera Model: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL) + "\n");
        builder.append("Camera Orientation: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION) + "\n");
        builder.append("Camera White Balance: " + getExifTag(exif, ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE) + "\n");

        builder = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```